# Symfony 3.4 Duplication of my User object in database

Tags: php, database, symfony

I have a very strange problem. With CAS authentication, when I have a user logging on, there is a check in the database to return a corresponding User object (which contains some attributes).

Among other things, the User entity contains an ArrayCollection () of Package (entity), ManyToMany.

This user can then download packages.
When it downloads one, the package is added to its ArrayCollection () (and so I have a new line in the association table between User and Packag, with the id of the User, and the id of the package).

Except that strangely, I can not handle the User entity correctly, because when I have one that downloads a package, there is duplication of the entire User object in the database, and this is the one -which benefits from adding the package in its ArrayCollection ().

In short, my User object does not pass correctly between pages.

My code :

When a user authenticates (CAS authentication) :

```
/**
     * Traitement personnalisé après récupération du token
     * 
     * Il est possible d'enrichir le token (attributs...) ou d'effectuer des contrôles supplémentaire
     * 
     * @param $token 
     *      Token d'authification généré
     * 
     * @return null
     */
    public function onSuccess($token){

        $mail = $this->ai->getMail();

        $token->setAttribute('mail', $mail);;   
        $token->setAttribute('typeAuth','cas');

        $user = $this->checkBDD($mail);
        $user = $this->serializer->serialize($user, 'json');

        $token->setAttribute('user',$user);

        

       // $user = $this->checkBDD($mail);
       // $token->setAttribute('user',$user);

    }
```

So we get the User object associated with it (or we create one if it is the first time it connects).

```
/**
 * Vérifie si l'utilisateur CAS existe et le crée sinon et renvoi l'objet
 * 
 * @return UserCas
 */
public function checkBDD($mail)
{
    $nb = $this->em->getRepository('PagesBundle:UserCas')->getIfUserCas($mail);

    if($nb == 0)
    {
        //création

        $user = new UserCas;

        $nbPackages = $this->em->getRepository('PagesBundle:Paquet')->getNombrePackages();

        $user->setMail($mail);
        $user->setNbTelechargementsAuto($nbPackages);
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    else
    {
        $user = $this->em->getRepository('PagesBundle:UserCas')->findOneByMail($mail);
    }

    return $user;

    }
```

The User object is then serialized and passed as an attribute in the token.

Then he has access to a Packages tab where he can download packages and their instructions.
If it downloads a package, then we add the package to its ArrayCollection.

```
/** 
     * Lorsque l'on clique sur un package à télécharger ou sa notice : Téléchargement
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/{type}/file", name="user_paquet_fileDDL")
     */
    public function paquetFileAction(Paquet $paquet, $type)
    {
        $downloadHandler = $this->get('vich_uploader.download_handler'); // On prépare le téléchargement

        if($type == "package") //Si l'utilisateur clique sur le lien du package, on lui donne le fichier package
        {
            $token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
            $typeAuth = $token->getAttribute('typeAuth');

            if($typeAuth == 'cas')
            {
                $user = $token->getAttribute('user');
                $user = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize($user, 'Site\PagesBundle\Entity\UserCas', 'json');
            }

            else
            {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //Récupération du manager
                //$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('PagesBundle:User')->setDDL("test"); //On décrémente le nombre de DDL pour l'utilisateur en question
                $user = $this->getUser();
            }

            $this->packageDDL($paquet,$user);

            return $downloadHandler->downloadObject($paquet, $fileField = 'paquetFile', Paquet::class, null);
        }

        else //Sinon c'est qu'il a cliqué sur le lien de la notice, alors on lui donne la notice associée au package
        {
            return $downloadHandler->downloadObject($paquet, $fileField = 'noticeFile', Paquet::class, null);
        }
        
    }
```

With this function:

```
public function packageDDL($paquet,$user)
    {
        $token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
        $typeAuth = $token->getAttribute('typeAuth');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //Récupération du manager
        $user->addPackage($paquet);
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        if($typeAuth == 'cas')
        {
            $data = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($user, 'json');
            $token->setAttribute('user',$data) ;
        }
    }
```

It calls the addPackage($paquet) function which is on a Trait.

```
public function addPackage($package)
{
    $this->packages[] = $package;
    $this->decDDL();
    
}
```

Then when this is done and saved (persist, flush), we re-serialize the User object and put it back in the token.
Well, it creates a new user.

A part of my User entity :

```
/**  
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Paquet")  
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="paquetsDDLUserCas") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */  
private $packages;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->packages = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->setEnabled(true);

}
```

What's wrong ? I don't understand

EDIT:

I deleted the serialization of my User. It works better now. But now, when I download a package, I've this :

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlNmA.png)

My file is not downloaded, but my database is edited !

UserCas.php:

```
<?php

namespace Site\PagesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Site\PagesBundle\Security\Traits\traitUser;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * UserCas
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_cas")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Site\PagesBundle\Repository\UserCasRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("mail")
 */
class UserCas
{

    use traitUser;

    
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nbTelechargementsAuto", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $nbTelechargementsAuto;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean")
     */
    private $enabled;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="mail", type="string")
     */
    private $mail;

    /**  
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Paquet")  
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="paquetsDDLUserCas") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */  
    private $packages;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->packages = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->setEnabled(true);

    }




    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMail()
    {
        return $this->mail;
    }

    public function setMail($mail)
    {
        $this->mail = $mail;
    }

    
    /**
     * Set enabled
     *
     * @param boolean $enabled
     *
     * @return UserCas
     */
    public function setEnabled($enabled)
    {
        $this->enabled = $enabled;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->enabled;
    }

}
```

Paquet.php:

```
<?php

namespace Site\PagesBundle\Entity;

use DateTimeImmutable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\Paquet;
use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Paquet
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="paquet")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Site\PagesBundle\Repository\PaquetRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Paquet
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**  
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="TypeUser")  
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Packages_des_TypesUser") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */  
    private $typeUser;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->typeUser = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /** 
     * Get TypeUser 
     * 
     * @return Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser 
     */ 
    public function getTypeUser() 
    { 
        return $this->typeUser; 
    }

    public function deleteTypeFromTypesUser(TypeUser $type)
    {
        $this->typeUser->removeElement($type);
    }



    /**
     * Set typeUser
     *
     * @param Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser $typeUser
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setTypeUser(Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser $typeUser)
    {
        $this->typeUser = $typeUser;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(min=5, max=255, minMessage="Le titre doit comporter au minimum 5 caractères")
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="urlPaquet", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $urlPaquet;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="paquet", fileNameProperty="urlPaquet")
     * @var File
     */
    private $paquetFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
    */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
 * @param File|UploadedFile $unPaquetFile
 *
 * @return Paquet
*/
public function setPaquetFile(File $unPaquetFile = null)
{
    $this->paquetFile = $unPaquetFile;

    if ($unPaquetFile) 
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }
        
    
    return $this;
}

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

/**
 * @return File|null
 */
public function getPaquetFile()
{
    return $this->paquetFile;
}


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="urlNotice", type="string", length=255,nullable=true)
     */
    private $urlNotice;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="notice", fileNameProperty="urlNotice",nullable=true)
     * @var File
     */
    private $noticeFile;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="commentaire", type="text")
     */
    private $commentaire;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set titre
     *
     * @param string $titre
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setTitre($titre)
    {
        $this->titre = $titre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get titre
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitre()
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }

    /**
     * Set urlPaquet
     *
     * @param string $urlPaquet
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setUrlPaquet($urlPaquet)
    {
        $this->urlPaquet = $urlPaquet;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get urlPaquet
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getUrlPaquet()
    {
        return $this->urlPaquet;
    }

    /**
     * @return File|null
     */
    public function getNoticeFile()
    {
        return $this->noticeFile;
    }

        /**
     * @param File|UploadedFile $uneNoticeFile
     *
     * @return Paquet
    */
    public function setNoticeFile(File $uneNoticeFile = null)
    {
        $this->noticeFile = $uneNoticeFile;

        if ($uneNoticeFile) 
        {
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }
        
    
        return $this;
}

    /**
     * Set urlNotice
     *
     * @param string $urlNotice
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setUrlNotice($urlNotice)
    {
        $this->urlNotice = $urlNotice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get urlNotice
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrlNotice()
    {
        return $this->urlNotice;
    }

    /**
     * Set commentaire
     *
     * @param string $commentaire
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setCommentaire($commentaire)
    {
        $this->commentaire = $commentaire;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get commentaire
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCommentaire()
    {
        return $this->commentaire;
    }
}
```

And after removing all that is serialization, I have in my method:

```
public function packageDDL($paquet,$user)
    {
        $token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
        $typeAuth = $token->getAttribute('typeAuth');

        dump($user);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //Récupération du manager
        $user->addPackage($paquet);
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        if($typeAuth == 'cas')
        {
            $data = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($user, 'json');
            $token->setAttribute('user',$data) ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: in the ``checkBDD`` function, have you checked that ``$nb`` doesn't return **0** all the time ?

Comment: Yes, I watched that. The first time, the $ nb is 0 and a User is created. And if I update, it is equal to 1, and there is no additional user created

Comment: How do you addPackage with $user->addPackage($paquet); if there is no such function defined in your User entity ?

Comment: With a Trait. My addPackage() function is in a Trait ^^

Comment: Is this trait properly made ? because there should not be any issue adding a package to an user from the method addPackage ?
Your method should look like :

public function addPackage(Package $package): self
{
    if (!$this->packages->contains($package)) {
        $this->packages[] = $package;
        //Uncomment if ManyToMany is in both side
        //$package->setUser($this);
    }
    return $this;
}

Comment: In the end, the problem has been reversed since I deleted the serializations. Now my database is well modified, but the download does not start and the user is redirected to a page with strange characters (I put a link in the edition of my post)

Comment: And for your function yes, it should work, but I do not take into account the condition of "if $ packages does not contain the package" because I intend to display only those it does not have, so no risk of duplication . The real problem is the redirection to the rather weird page

Comment: Have you tried returning a BinaryFileResponse instead ?

Comment: Where ? I do not know much about it, sorry

Comment: Well just read the doc about BinaryFileResponse on the symfony website and use it instead of your return $downloadHandler->downloadObject..

Comment: The problem is that I use VichUploaderBundle for this. Is it good to modify the code that vichuploader proposes in its doc?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with

```
$em->persist($user);
```

In your packageDDL function

You do not need to persist the entity User since it already exist.
You just want to flush it. So just modify your function for :

```
public function packageDDL($paquet,$user)
    {
        $token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
        $typeAuth = $token->getAttribute('typeAuth');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //Récupération du manager
        $user->addPackage($paquet);
        $em->flush();

        if($typeAuth == 'cas')
        {
            $data = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($user, 'json');
            $token->setAttribute('user',$data) ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: By removing this line, I can download the files and there is no more user duplication. However, my database is no longer affected, the package is not added to those of my user. And I noticed also thanks to a dump of my $ user once deserialized that the ID had passed to null

Comment: Can I see your user and package entity ?